# Eigen Half.h compilation error: ‘struct Eigen::half’ has no member named ‘x’

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I'm trying to compile some code that uses the same version of Eigen as TensorFlow 2.2 (https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/tree/52a2fbbb008a47c5e3fb8ac1c65c2feecb0c511c). The abbreviated command line I'm using to do so is:

```
tools/cc/gcc74/bin/nvcc-wrapper -nostdinc -isystem external/gcc_7_4/usr/include/c++/7 ... 
  '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0' -DBOOST_MATH_NO_LONG_DOUBLE_MATH_FUNCTIONS -g1 -O2 '-std=c++14' ... 
  -fPIC -DEIGEN_MPL2_ONLY '-DEIGEN_MAX_ALIGN_BYTES=16' '-DEIGEN_MAX_STATIC_ALIGN_BYTES=16' 
  '-D__CUDACC_VER_MAJOR__=10' '-D__CUDACC_VER_MINOR__=0' -DEIGEN_HAS_CUDA_FP16 -iquote ...
```

This results in a number of compilation errors:

```
In file included from external/eigen/Eigen/Core:165:0,
                 from external/eigen/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from ...:
external/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/arch/Default/Half.h: In member function ‘Eigen::half::operator bool() const’:
external/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/arch/Default/Half.h:139:13: error: ‘x’ was not declared in this scope
     return (x & 0x7fff) != 0;
             ^
In file included from external/eigen/Eigen/Core:165:0,
                 from external/eigen/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from ...:
external/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/arch/Default/Half.h: In function ‘Eigen::half Eigen::half_impl::operator-(const Eigen::half&)’:
external/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/arch/Default/Half.h:342:10: error: ‘struct Eigen::half’ has no member named ‘x’
   result.x = a.x ^ 0x8000;
          ^
external/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/arch/Default/Half.h:342:16: error: ‘const struct Eigen::half’ has no member named ‘x’
   result.x = a.x ^ 0x8000;
                ^
external/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/arch/Default/Half.h: In function ‘Eigen::half_impl::__half_raw Eigen::half_impl::raw_uint16_to_half(short unsigned int)’:
external/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/arch/Default/Half.h:398:5: error: ‘Eigen::half_impl::__half_raw {aka struct __half}’ has no member named ‘x’
   h.x = x;
     ^
external/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/arch/Default/Half.h: In function ‘Eigen::half_impl::__half_raw Eigen::half_impl::float_to_half_rtne(float)’:
external/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/arch/Default/Half.h:426:5: error: ‘Eigen::half_impl::__half_raw {aka struct __half}’ has no member named ‘x’
   o.x = static_cast<unsigned short>(0x0u);
     ^
```

Removing `-DEIGEN_HAS_CUDA_FP16` causes these errors to go away, but then other code that expects a valid `__half` stops working.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That Eigen version is more than a year old. Are you able to upgrade this? If the problem persist with an up-to-date version, you should file an issue (on TF or Eigen, depending on whether you can reproduce the problem independent of TF)

Comment: The commit in question is not included in the most recent Eigen release (3.3.9).  The commit in question is included in the `3.4.0-rc1` tag, and discussion here https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/issues/1851 says "It looks like the commit in question reverts a change that was never applied to the 3.3 branch, so we should be good to go." but some of the parent commits aren't reverts. In any case, 3.3.9 fails with a different error (`error: ‘Vector’ in namespace ‘Eigen’ does not name a template type`).

Comment: The same errors happen with the head of master.

Comment: Can you file a [bug report](https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/issues/new?issuable_template=Bug%20Report) with a [mre]?